# Retrieving the top 5 users with the most views on their posts in total

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have 3 tables:

- users
- posts
- visits

Each time a post gets visited, a new visit will be inserted in the following format:

```
| id | post_id
```

My post table has:

```
| id | text | user_id ...
```

I'm trying to retrieve the TOP 5 users with the most views on their posts in total.
For example:

1. User1 -> 4
2. User2 -> 2

```sql
SELECT count(v.id) AS count FROM visits AS v RIGHT JOIN pastes AS p ON v.post_id = p.id RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON id = p.id
```

But all I get is an array with "count: 12".

Comment: I would expect a `group by` to be there somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

nbk has answered already, I have set up your tables in a SQL fiddle, this makes it easier to play around. Consider using this tool for any more questions, because that makes it easier to talk about table structure etc.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45220f/2

To elaborate more on the question/answer already given: You need to group by a column, so that all columns sharing the same value will be grouped to a single row in the result. Then you can use aggregate functions on this group, like `count`. There are other aggregate functions like `sum` (to add numbers in a group). For more information see the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html .

Answer (score 0):

As you want the total vies for one single user

But the part with the user is only a guess , because you didn't post the user table

```
SELECT u.name,count(*) AS 'count'
FROM visits AS v 
RIGHT JOIN pastes AS p ON v.post_id = p.id 
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id 
GROUP BY u.id,u.name
ORDER BY `coun`t DESC
LIMIT 5
```